# Nagios - NRPE commands definitions

Tags: command, nagios, nrpe

I have a Nagios server with 10 servers monitored. I'm using hostgroups and NRPE to check Cpu and Disks.

But by default, `check_disk` command definition doesn't exist in the NRPE configuration file.

Is there any way to define these alias commands only on the Nagios Server ?

I would to avoid to change the NRPE config file on each server...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios server connects to the monitored server via NRPE and execute the defined command in the remote `nrpe.cfg` file. So, the command must exist in the nrpe config file of the server to be monitored.

In the other hand, the list of the nrpe commands to be executed in the mentioned remote server is located under the nagios server: `.../nagios/configurations/objects/server1.cfg`

To summarize:

In Nagios server:
Define the command in the corresponding server's cfg file. (The name of the check, the servers/server groups to be checked etc.)

In Monitored server (for every individual server):
Add the command in `nrpe.cfg`. (Show the checker script's path and give parameters.)